# Using ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS together with ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am creating an app where i would like to use both the drop down list navigation and tab navigation on an actionbar. But i can not figure out how to do this without implementing the actionbar as a custom view which would mess up a lot of the nice built in features.

So what is the best way to get both of these navigation modes at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android will not build both of these for you. You can use the ViewPagerIndicator library to make an emulated tab bar for a ViewPager, which is probably the easiest way to do this.